# Will (global) static variables be destroyed at program end?

Tags: c++, destructor, lifetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does C++ call destructors for global and class static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204608/does-c-call-destructors-for-global-and-class-static-variables)

What is the lifetime of

- global `MyClass myclass;`
- global `static MyClass myclass;`
- global `const MyClass myclass;`
- global `static const MyClass myclass;`
- function local `static MyClass myclass;` when its initialization actually occured
- global `static constexpr MyClass myclass;` in C++11

and especially **will they be destroyed on regular program end** (i.e. `main` is left without an error)? Where does the standard states so.

I noticed that a *private destructor* prevents the creation of all those variables. But if I remember correctly it was explicitly mentioned somewhere that some static data may be put into a static data section and loaded pre-constructed, already. This would imply for me that no destructor would be called. And this would imply I am allowed to define such a variable...

Comment: You could put a `cout` statement in the destructor, and see for yourself.

Comment: @Beta "Try it" often fails in C and C++ due to implementation defined and undefined behavior.

Comment: @Beta you are right of course. Let me add in my question that I want to know where to look in the standard.

Comment: @delnan: good point (although in this case it is well defined).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The destructors of file or namespace scope objects get called when the control flow leaves `main()`.

If an exception leaves `main()` then it's implementation defined whether the destructors of any objects get called. With modern compilers the destructors won't be called in this case to allow easy inspection of the program state when the unhandled exception was thrown. Early C++ implementations used exception mechanism based on `setjmp`/`longjmp` which would unwind the stack while searching for the exception handler and hence calling destructors even if no suitable exception handler was eventually found.

If an application terminates with `_exit()` or `_Exit()` or `std::quick_exit()` no destructors get called.

Comment: The standard says that if an exception is not caught, `std::terminate()` is called.  `std::terminate()`, by default, calls `abort()`. And `abort()` is not allowed to call destructors.

Comment: Also, of course: destructors get called when `exit()` is called.  Returning from `main` causes `exit` to be called.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Right, thanks. The functions Maxim mentioned are probably in a specific implementation which then call the standard functions.

Comment: @towi `_Exit()` and `std::quick_exit()` are standard C++; the former is also standard C.  `_exit()` is standard Unix.

Comment: @JamesKanze: oh, you are right. found it 15.4 and 18.1. in c++11 std.

Answer (score 6):

The destructors for objects with static lifetime (all of the cases you
mention define objects with static lifetime—although I don't think
that an object in a `constexpr` can have a non-trivial destructor) are
called from within `exit()`, in the reverse order the objects were
constructed.

Returning from `main` causes `exit` to be called with the return value,
so returning from main will cause these destructors to be called.  Other
means of program termination (`abort()`, assertion failure, `_exit()`,
etc.) will not call destructors.

If the objects are in a DLL (`.so` under Unix), the destructors will
normally be called when the DLL is unloaded.

Comment: Why on earth did I not think of *"an object in a `constexpr` can [not] have a non-trivial destructor"*. Not a good example, I have to think about that.

Comment: @towi I'm not at all sure about it.  I haven't looked it up, and I'm not sure where I'd have to start looking.  But logically: to be used as a `constexpr` means that the value can be known at compile time, which in turm means that it's invariant.  And a non-trivial destructor would mean that the value would cease to exist.

Comment: @Towi I've just checked.  A `constexpr` variable must have a _literal
type_ (§7.1.5/9), and one of the constraints for a type to be a literal
type is that it have a trivial destructor (§3.9/10).

Comment: +1 for the detail, though it's relevant to note C++14 relaxed a lot of restrictions on what can be a `constexpr`.