# how delete class variable in struct?

Tags: c++

```
InitMyObject(MyObject* ptr)
{
    *ptr = MyObject();
}

struct Data
{
    MyObject obj;
};

extern Data data;


// ...

InitMyObject(&data.obj); 

delete &data.obj; // ? is this ok
```

How I can delete (call deconstructor) `data.obj`, I also try `Data::obj` as pointer (nullptr default) then pass the pointer but crashed on Init.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?  What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: `delete` is only used to destroy objects created with `new`. You didn't use `new` so `delete` shouldn't be used either.

Comment: `obj` will be automatically destroyed whenever `data` happens to get destroyed. You haven't really shown what `data` is so we can't say if or when its destruction own would occur.

Comment: You don't; it is destroyed when its containing object is destroyed. There is a list of good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @StephenNewell i try clean up static data when program exit so i want call deconstruct on my obj variabl which in static struct

Comment: _"i want call deconstruct on my obj variabl which in static struct"_ that will happen [without your intervention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728535/will-global-static-variables-be-destroyed-at-program-end).

Comment: I'm _guessing_ about the code that's missing from your question, but it is likely that your `*ptr = MyObject();` is replacing a default-constructed `MyObject` with an identical default-constructed `MyObject`.  There already exists an object at that location.

Comment: @t.niese it could be!  Without knowing what `MyObject` is, I'm _stressing_ the _guessing_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can delete (call deconstructor) data.obj

The destructor of `data` will destroy its subobjects. Since `data` has static storage, it is automatically destroyed at the end of the program.

> ```
> delete &data.obj; // ? is this ok
> ```

No. You may only delete the result of a non-placement new expression. You may not delete a pointer to a member object.