# Destruction order in C++

Tags: c++, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
class X{
public:
    X(int n = 0) : n(n) {}
    ~X() {std::cout << n;}
    int n;
};
void main()
{
    X a(1);
    const X b(2);
    static X c(3);
}
```

Output is `213`, I thought the destructor uses a LIPO stack, so why it doesn't destruct in a reverse order `321`?

I'm pretty confused and I'd like to know more about it. Thank you so much.

Comment: [Covered in documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). Skip down to the paragraph on static storage duration.

Comment: `void main()` is not allowed in Standard C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` and `b` are of automatic duration, destroyed when the block ends. `c` is of static duration, destroyed when the program terminates. LIFO order only applies to objects destroyed at the same point in the program.

Answer (score 1):

It is calling the destructors in reverse order, but a static variable has a different lifetime.

See [Does C++ call destructors for global and class static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204608/does-c-call-destructors-for-global-and-class-static-variables) which explains that variables with a global lifetime are destructed sometime after `main` returns.

Answer (score 1):

That is LIFO. `a` and `b` are destructed in reverse order when `main` returns, `c` is destructed at some undetermined point between when `main` returns and the program actually exits (because it's static, tied to the lifetime of the program, not `main` itself).