# Why adding a cpp file to be compiled with Cmake might lead to a segmentation fault in the middle of execution of a program?

Tags: c++, cmake, segmentation-fault

I compile and run program normally as follows:

```
set(A_SRC a.hpp a.cpp)
```

When I add second compilation target as following:

```
set(A_SRC a.hpp a.cpp b.hpp b.cpp)
```

It leads to a SegFault during execution `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, coredump is has no valuable information about the cause.

b.hpp is not used anywhere, all the code / functions inside b are inside a separate namespace. b.hpp share similarity with one of the linked libraries.

What could be a cause of the segfault? How can one cause a SegFault by simply compiling more code?

##### More info JIC:

Stacktrace:

```
#0  0x00007f489ba27550 in ?? ()
#1  <signal handler called>
#2  0x00007f489ba27550 in ?? ()
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x00007f495daf87b1 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f465c8e9c66 in __gthread_cond_timedwait (__cond=0x55fdf3180b88,
    __mutex=0x55fdf3180b60, __abs_timeout=0x7ffe36106dd0)
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/9/bits/gthr-default.h:872
#6  0x00007f465c8eb676 in std::condition_variable::__wait_until_impl<std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > (this=0x55fdf3180b88, __lock=..., __atime=...)
    at /usr/include/c++/9/condition_variable:188
#7  0x00007f465c8eab4a in std::condition_variable::wait_until<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > (this=0x55fdf3180b88,
    __lock=..., __atime=...) at /usr/include/c++/9/condition_variable:121
#8  0x00007f465c8ea1c5 in std::condition_variable::wait_for<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> > (
    this=0x55fdf3180b88, __lock=..., __rtime=...)
...
```

And the other threads aren't helpful either:

```
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id                       Frame
* 1    Thread 0x7f495d78c740 (LWP 18)  0x00007f489ba27550 in ?? ()
  2    Thread 0x7f4661aea700 (LWP 121) 0x00007f495d86f3bf in clock_nanosleep ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
  3    Thread 0x7f480bcac700 (LWP 138) 0x00007f495daf8376 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
    () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0x7f48a1cc6700 (LWP 128) 0x00007f495d8a4aff in poll ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
  5    Thread 0x7f47bdc9f700 (LWP 145) 0x00007f495daf8376 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2
    () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
  6    Thread 0x7f4885cc1700 (LWP 130) 0x00007f495d8b2c90 in accept4 ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Comment: I really don't think this is a CMake problem. This looks like something wrong with your C++ code.

Comment: "What could be a cause of the segfault? How can one cause a SegFault by simply compiling more code?" Hard to say. We would really need to know the source code to help you more. Please consider making a SSCCE.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Most likely the reason is your code has some bug / undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> What could be a cause of the segfault? How can one cause a SegFault by simply compiling more code?

This is strange but perhaps the extra source code you are adding is executing code somehow.

Perhaps something related to globals. I had issues on the past working on embedded systems where global variables allocated dynamic memory.

[Does C++ call destructors for global and class static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204608/does-c-call-destructors-for-global-and-class-static-variables)

Or you are using predefined functions that implicitly execute logic. For example DLLMain. I know you are on unix but the point still stands.

Try compiling with higher warning levels. Your code might be violating C++ rules like ODR.

Or using a tool like Valgrind to help you debug the issue.

Comment: Advising against globals, OK. That can complicate program maintenance, certainly an issue on multi-millions dollar projects. But suggesting it has something to do with `std::` ? Or containers? That's just voodoo programming.,

Comment: I've updated my answer with clearer language of my original intent.