# what is the destruction order between global object and static variable?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Object destruction in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403055/object-destruction-in-c)

Suppose we have two classes, one is called `Array` and the other one is called `MessageOnExit`.

Assume the `Array` class has a static data member called `counter`.

Here are the classes:

```
class Array {
public:
    static int counter;
    Array(){counter++;}
    ~Array(){counter--;}
};

class MessageOnExit {
public:
    ~MessageOnExit(){cout << Array::counter;}
};
```

The following is the **"main"** using these classes:

```
// static variable definition
int Array::counter;
// global object definition
MessageOnExit message;

void main() {
    Array a1, a2;
    Array a3(a1);
}
```

The first two declarations will change `counter` to be 2 ensues two calls of the Empty/Default constructor 
The third declaration won't change the `counter` because the Default copy constructor will be called.

Now when the `main` execution is done, the value of the static member `counter`will be `-1` ensues the destructors calls (after a1, a2 and a3 are desroyed), and then the `message` destructor will be called, printing this value (`-1`).

My question is how do we know the static member `counter` is still alive and available when the `message` destructor is being called.

Also if I change the static/global object/variable definition order, that is, `message` is defined before `counter`, the value remains `-1`.

To summarize, no matter what changes I do, when the program terminates the message destructor success to access the static member `counter` and I don't understand why is that. As far as I understand if the global object `message` is defined first its destructor will be called last and therefore the `counter` value won't be available for its destructor.

Thanks in advance!
Guy

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728535/will-global-static-variables-be-destroyed-at-program-end), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204608/does-c-call-destructors-for-global-and-class-static-variables) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087600/is-a-c-destructor-guaranteed-not-to-be-called-until-the-end-of-the-block).

Comment: Using an object after it has been destroyed is not a diagnosed error, its undefined behavior, so anything might happen -- the code might appear to work fine one day and break the next.

Comment: I edited away all the bold text because it had the effect of emphasizing parts of the text that shouldn't have been. I either removed it or changed them to code-quotes. You can add back bolding in some places if you feel it's really needed.

Comment: Reopen this question. The important point here is that a static object with trivial destructor is never destroyed; see aschepler's answer. That is not stated clearly in the answers to the other questions,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard section 3.8 says:

> The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>
> - if T is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or
> - the storage which the object occupies is reused or released.

Now `int` is not a class type, and since `Array::counter` has static storage duration, its storage is never released.  So the lifetime of `Array::counter` never ends, and you can safely access it from any destructor you want!